# Difference between SOAP and RESTful

Tags: android

What is the difference between `SOAP` and `RESTful` Architecture and how I can use them in Android? My application is a  booking engine car, I am still confused. Can someone help me to see the difference between those, and how I can Apply in an `Android` application with example please. Also how i can use the `MVC`  Architecture

Answer (score 0):

**REST** (REST describes a set of architectural principles by which data can be transmitted over a standardized interface) is almost always going to be faster. The main advantage of **SOAP** (SOAP defines a standard communication protocol specification for XML-based message exchange)is that it provides a mechanism for services to describe themselves to clients, and to advertise their existence.

**REST** is much more lightweight and can be implemented using almost any tool, leading to lower bandwidth and shorter learning curve. However, the clients have to know what to send and what to expect.

In general, When you're publishing an API to the outside world that is either complex or likely to change, **SOAP** will be more useful. Other than that, **REST** is usually the better option.

Comment: Words seemed to me like those we see Please in the internet sir I want a living example to unserdtand more  I do not understand how to apply or how to coding according this two architecture ? Is that programming is side of java android in eclipse or in  the api for exemple getliststudent.php can you explain more

Comment: Okay . Please read this article http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/